# MongoDB not able to authenticate on the replicaset

Tags: mongodb, authentication, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, replicaset

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.
Mongo Version: MongoDB shell version v4.4.14.
I have configured a 3 node mongo replica set on AWS EC2 instances. To replicate the same environment, I created AMI's and launched the ec2 instances in another account. I am able to run the mongod service, but not able to authenticate and connect to mongo. I used to connect using the command below:

```
mongo -u "adminuser" -p "adminpass" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

This works in source machines, but in new instances, I am getting the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.14
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Mongo logs doesn't show any specific error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:30:02.506+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","speculative":true,"principalName":"srrclusteradmin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"127.0.0.1:60426","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"srrclusteradmin\" for db \"admin\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:30:02.506+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"srrclusteradmin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"127.0.0.1:60426","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"srrclusteradmin\" for db \"admin\""}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:30:02.507+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn6","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60426","connectionId":6,"connectionCount":0}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:30:54.948+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656621054:948266][2295:0x7f81a1103700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 254, snapshot max: 254 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 190"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:31:54.956+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656621114:955999][2295:0x7f81a1103700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 256, snapshot max: 256 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 190"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:32:54.965+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656621174:965737][2295:0x7f81a1103700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 258, snapshot max: 258 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 190"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:33:54.973+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656621234:973751][2295:0x7f81a1103700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 260, snapshot max: 260 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 190"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:34:53.767+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20712,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheReap","msg":"Sessions collection is not setup; waiting until next sessions reap interval","attr":{"error":"NamespaceNotFound: config.system.sessions does not exist"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:34:53.767+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20714,   "ctx":"LogicalSessionCacheRefresh","msg":"Failed to refresh session cache, will try again at the next refresh interval","attr":{"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-30T20:34:54.981+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"WTCheckpointThread","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1656621294:981888][2295:0x7f81a1103700], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 262, snapshot max: 262 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 190"}}
```

mongo configuration is below:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /mongodata
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: localhost, 10.0.2.56

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

security:
  keyFile: /mongo-security/keyfile.txt
#  transitionToAuth: true

#operationProfiling:
#replication:
replication:
  replSetName: mongors

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

mongod.service (--auth flag is added)

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --auth --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note: following commands are successful:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.14connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodbImplicit session: session { "id" : UUID("79d782b8-f2c4-464d-9537-00b561bc01ec") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.14> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.auth("adminuser", passwordPrompt())
Enter password:
Error: Authentication failed.
0
>
```

Somehow the password which is working earlier, isn't working in this new machine. Kindly advice how to get access and authenticate to retrieve the data.

Few more output with error for reference:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.14
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("b680471c-cc8b-4ea5-a251-b30b6a528448") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.14
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show collections
Warning: unable to run listCollections, attempting to approximate collection names by parsing connectionStatus
> show dbs
uncaught exception: Error: listDatabases failed:{
        "topologyVersion" : {
                "processId" : ObjectId("62be0e1f90d1de371954e891"),
                "counter" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
        "code" : 13435,
        "codeName" : "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs/<@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147:19
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:99:12
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:937:13
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:819:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

Comment: I would prefer to enable authorization in config file `security.authorization: enabled` instead of command line option `--auth`. Anyway, you set `security.keyFile` which implicitly also enables authorization.

Comment: The error is this: `"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"` You did not initiate the replica set, see [Deploy Replica Set With Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Before creating the AMI on EC2, I had configured the replica set and Authentication flag. As I am not able to authenticate and list the database or run any command, I feel it has something to do with authentication. I can't initiate the replica set unless I get access to the db.

Comment: You must connect to the replicaset, e.g. like `mongodb://adminuser:adminpass@first_host:27017,second_host:27017/admin?authSource=admin&replicaSet=mongors`

Comment: The user does not exist: `"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"srrclusteradmin\" for db \"admin\"`. Why do you consider `Error: Authentication failed.` as "*following commands are successful:*"? Did you add the new node to the replica set?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Before creating the AMI, I was able to authenticate using "srrclusteradmin". If you see at the very end of my question, I am able to run the mongo command but it doesn't allow me to see the database or perform any query because of authentication. And the users which I had created are not found or able to authenticate. I am assuming the users are created in the mongo's db path and nowhere else. Is that correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "users are created in the mongo's db path and nowhere else "? It does not make any sense. Users are created in the database.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I referred to storage:  dbPath: config value which stores the data written in mongodb. Is there any encryption happening when the users are created with the key file?

Comment: The key file is used for internal authentication within the Replica set. It has nothing to do with the users you create.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the statements in your question and comments are wrong:

> Mongo logs doesn't show any specific error

It shows several errors:

```
"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"srrclusteradmin\" for db \"admin\""}}
"error":"NotYetInitialized: Replication has not yet been configured"
```

> Note: following commands are successful:
>
> ```
> db.auth("adminuser", passwordPrompt())
> Enter password:
> Error: Authentication failed.
> ```

Why do you consider "Authentication failed" as "successful"?

> I can't initiate the replica set unless I get access to the db.

No, first you need to initiate the Replica Set, then you can create a user and then you can use it for authorization.

Initiate your Replica Set (see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/), then it should work.

The basic command is `rs.initiate()`, you may put some more parameters to it.

net:
port: 27017
bindIp: localhost, 10.0.2.56